# Laravel The GET method is not supported for this route when redirecting back()

Tags: php, laravel

I have Laravel project and there is a post route that I pass a parameter in the URL and a form in the Request

```
Route::post('/gc/verifierQR-{qr_url}', [UserController::class, 'inquiryResult'])->name('inquiry.result');
```

this route returns to a view file and in this view there is change language button

```
<div class="nav-item">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="bg-transparent border-0" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1"
            data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <a class="nav-link text-white"><i class="fas fa-globe me-2"></i> العربية <i
                    class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu border-0 shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item fw-bold" href="{{ route('lang', $arabic_locale) }}"><img
                        src="{{ asset('images/egypt-flag.png') }}" class="egypt-flag">
                    العربية</a></li>
            <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('lang', $english_locale) }}"><img
                        src="{{ asset('images/usa-flag.png') }}" class="egypt-flag">
                    English</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

the route of language changing

```
Route::get('/language/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    app()->setLocale($locale);
    session()->put('locale', $locale);
    return redirect()->back();
})->name('lang');
```

but in this page when I change the language and redirect back() I found this error

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

Comment: are you returning a view from a POST route? POST REDIRECT GET ... you can't redirect back to the POST route (redirects cause GET requests)

Answer (score 0):

When we say redirect, we usually mean the browser, and you can not change the method which the browser uses to open pages (which is `GET`).

- Either redirect to another separate route.
- Or allow both `GET` and `POST` methods (for your already existing route).

  > Instead of normal POST route:
  >
  > ```php
  > Route::post('my-url', function () {
  >    return view('my-view');
  > })->name('my-route');
  > ```
  >
  > Do something like:
  >
  > ```php
  > use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  > use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
  >
  > Route::match(['post', 'get'], 'my-url', function (Request $request) {
  >    return view('my-view');
  > })->name('my-route');
  > ```

Comment: how to allow the both methods?

Comment: @OsamaAmr see edit (example added); note that `Route::match(...)` method accepts parameters like the `Route::post(...)` method does, just with first argument as extra.

Comment: I get error page, This page isn't working, TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: @OsamaAmr that probably means that, your route redirect to each other non-stop, or is ALWAYS redirecting to itself (so answer remains the same, but add check in `callback` to return `view` if request-type is GET, instead of redirecting).

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple. The route or url where you returned back definately a post route. you can use any instead of get and post.